# How do I implement notifications

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose

Can anybody please point me in the right direction?

I have made a message board as my first MERN project and am wondering how to integrate notifications for my private message feature. I don't think that sending an axios request every second seems like the right idea, is there a better way and how can I implement it?

I have heard of push messaging but have no idea about it...

Many thanks :)

Comment: You can use websockets to keep a connection between the client/api open, this way you can send messages between them. For example, you can send a message from the API to the client when a new message was received.

Comment: I suggest taking a look at socket.io for real time data traffic. Docs: https://socket.io/docs/

Comment: Ah, socket.io... I was sort of hoping there'd be an easier way. Anyway, thanks, I'll give it a shot!

Comment: If you want a simpler solution, use Server-Sent event, [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-server-sent-events-build-realtime-app) has a great tutorial on how to use it with React framework. I personally think websocket / socket.io is a bit overkill for a notification.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking it was overkill, but I plan on adding a simple chat room anyway, so I may as well give it a shot. Thanks though :)

Comment: I would also take a look at Firebase messaging. I personally love this solution